# Spring -- allow overriding THAT particular bean only

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, bean-validation

So I need to override a bean provided by a dependency in order to customize some configuration.

Is there any way to allow overriding just for THAT particular name?

I don't want to set

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

That's scary. I just want to override one particular named bean and disallow overriding in all other instances.

** **EDIT** **

```
    @Bean
    @Primary
    fun vaadinAuthenticationSuccessHandler(
            httpService: HttpService,
            vaadinRedirectStrategy: VaadinRedirectStrategy
    ): VaadinAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
        return VaadinUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler(httpService, vaadinRedirectStrategy, "/")
    }
```

results in

```
The bean 'vaadinAuthenticationSuccessHandler', defined in class path resource [n/c/s/config/security/VaadinAwareSecurityConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [org/vaadin/spring/security/config/VaadinSharedSecurityConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.
```

It's worth noting that similar code I've seen actually uses

```
@Bean(name = VaadinSharedSecurityConfiguration.VAADIN_AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS_HANDLER_BEAN)
```

(which doesn't make a difference, but it's worth noting all the same)

Comment: did you able to find workaround?

Answer (score 3):

In one of your `@Configuration` class, you can declare a `@Bean` with the same class as the one coming from your dependency library and mark it as `@Primary` to override the bean.

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public BeanClassFromDependency mrBean() {
        return new YourOwnImplementationForBeanClassFromDependency();
    }
}
```

Subsequently, you can autowire as usual.

```
@Autowired
private BeanClassFromDependency theBeanThatGotAway;
```

Comment: it doesn't work because you're trying to create a new bean with the exact same name. Give your new bean a unique name like @Bean(name="mrBean") and mark it with @Primary.